# Can not modify classes of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have following elements in the page:

```
<div class="cl1 cl2"></div>
<div class="cl1 cl2"></div>
<div class="cl1 cl2"></div>
```

When I run this code:

```
<script>
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("cl1");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        console.log(i + ": " + elems[i].className);
    }
</script>
```

I can see:

```
0 cl1 cl2
1 cl1 cl2
2 cl1 cl2
```

in console.

But this code:

```
<script>
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("cl1");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        console.log(i + ": " + elems[i].className);
        elems[i].className = 'cl3'; // or = '' (removing all classes)
    }
</script>
```

gives:

```
0 cl1 cl2
1 cl1 cl2
```

on first run, and:

```
0 cl1 cl2
```

on the second run.

What is the reason of not modifying all the elements? I can see that `elems.length` is reducing when we touch `elems[i].className`, but what is the reason?

If we put `var n = elems.length` and change for-loop with `i < n` we will get `Cannot read property 'className' of undefined` error.

The question is how to modify all the classes from the first time?

Because I believe the following code looks very silly:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("cl1");
while (elems.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        console.log(i + ": " + elems[i].className);
        elems[i].className = 'cl3';
    }
    elems = document.getElementsByClassName("cl1");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that items is a live NodeList, meaning whenever you access items.length, the list is re-evaluated.
When you delete elements, the list becomes shorter, but you keep the index.

You could convert the NodeList to an array first

```
    var items = [].slice.call(doc.getElementsByClassName('foo'));
```

The array size won't change when you delete the DOM elements.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is very suitable for script I'm working with.

Comment: Instead of copying, you can also iterate the NodeList backwards.

Comment: @Francis Avila, yeah, you are right, thanks. Is is really much more easier.

Comment: Notice that you can also use: `var items = document.querySelectorAll(".foo")` that returns a non-live NodeList, so you don't need array conversion. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll

Answer (score 1):

The `getElementsByClassName` function returns a NodeList, not an array. NodeList objects are **live** — they track the DOM as it changes. (*edit* — Turns out that not all NodeList objects are live, but the ones that come back from that function are.)

When you change the class of the first element, it stops being part of the list of elements. Thus, when you increment "i", you skip one.

You can convert the NodeList object to an array (see the answer from @ama2) or you can just not change "i" of you're removing elements from the selected set.

Comment: Not all *NodeLists* are live. There exist static ones. (I'm not sure which DOM function returns such static *NodeLists*).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas well that's interesting; learn something every day :-)

Comment: Zakas wrote about it in [this article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/28/why-is-getelementsbytagname-faster-that-queryselectorall/)